# How to use R to get all pairs from two column with index

Tags: r, combinations

I would like to use R to get all pairs from two column with index. It may need some loop to finish this function. For example, turn two columns with the gene name and index:

```
 a 1,
 b 1,
 c 1,
 d 2,
 e 2
```

into a new matrix

```
 a b 1, 
 b c 1,
 a c 1,
 d e 2
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: There were many  functions that can be used for correlation, such as `cor()`, `MINE()`. However, it is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `tidyverse` option using `combn` on a grouped data.frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(index) %>% 
        summarise(gene = list(as_data_frame(t(combn(gene, 2))))) %>% 
        unnest(.sep = '_')

## # A tibble: 4 × 3
##   index gene_V1 gene_V2
##   <int>   <chr>   <chr>
## 1     1       a       b
## 2     1       a       c
## 3     1       b       c
## 4     2       d       e
```

The same logic can be replicated in base R:

```
df2 <- aggregate(gene ~ index, df, function(x){t(combn(x, 2))})

do.call(rbind, apply(df2, 1, data.frame))

##   index gene.1 gene.2
## 1     1      a      b
## 2     1      a      c
## 3     1      b      c
## 4     2      d      e
```

---

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(gene = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), index = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("gene", "index"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks! @alistaire

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'index', we get the `combn` of 'gene', `transpose` it and set the names of the 2nd and 3rd column (if needed).

```
library(data.table)
setnames(setDT(df)[, transpose(combn(gene, 2, FUN = list)), 
             by = index], 2:3, paste0("gene", 1:2))[]
#   index gene1 gene2
#1:     1     a     b
#2:     1     a     c
#3:     1     b     c
#4:     2     d     e
```

Comment: Thanks very much ! @akrun